# Traversing two strings at a time python

Tags: python

I have two strings and I want to print them one character at a time alternatively. Like say

```
s1 = "Hi"
s2 = "Giy"

for c,d in s1,s2:
    print c
    print d
```

I expected the output to be `HGiiy`. However, I get the output `Hi`.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
In [7]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [8]: s1="Hi"

In [9]: s2="Giy"

In [10]: "".join("".join(x) for x in izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue=""))
Out[10]: 'HGiiy'
```

or using a simple `for` loop:

```
s1="Hi"
s2="Giy"
ans=""
for i in range(min(len(s1),len(s2))):
    ans+=s1[i]+s2[i]
ans += s1[i+1:]+s2[i+1:]    
print ans                 #prints HGiiy
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip()`:

```
for c, d in zip(s1, s2):
    print c, d,
```

Note that this does limit the loop to the *shortest* of the strings.

If you need *all* characters, use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for c, d in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''):
    print c, d,
```

Your version looped over the tuple `(s1, s2)`, so it would print `s1` first, then `s2`.

Comment: UV, but would still be nice to know what the mistake was.

Comment: The output then is `H G i i` and not `H G i i y`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's an explanation of why that doesn't work:

When you write:

```
for c, d in s1, s2:
    # ...
```

It means:

```
for c, d in [s1, s2]:
    # ...
```

Which is the same as:

```
for s in [s1, s2]:
    c, d = s
    # ../
```

When `s` is `Hi`, the letters get unpacked into `c` and `d` - `c == 'H'`, `d == 'i'`. When you try to do the same thing with `Giy`, python cannot unpack it, since there are three letters but only two variables.

---

As already mentioned, you  want to use `zip_longest`

Comment: Can't I do it using simple loops ?

Comment: @CSSS: IMO, `for c, d in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''):` _is_ a simple loop.

Comment: NameError: name 'zip_longest' is not defined

Comment: Well yeah, you have to import it first: `from itertools import zip_longest`

Comment: you can, check my latest answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function,

```
   def  mergeStrings(a, b):
        s = ''
        count = 0
        for i in range(min(len(a),len(b))):
            s+=a[i]
            s+=b[i]
            count+=1
        s+= a[count:] if len(a) > len(b) else b[count:]
        return s
```