# How to arrange two strings alternatively?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Traversing two strings at a time python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208126/traversing-two-strings-at-a-time-python)

Here I have question that how to concate two strings as their words are appear one after another.. I mean as an e.g. If the first strinng is "abc" and second one is "defgh" then the final answer should be "adbecfgh"...

here is my code but it appear in the same line

```
x = raw_input ('Enter 1st String: ')
y = raw_input ('Enter 2st String: ')
z = [x, y]
a = ''.join(z)
print (a)
```

Can anybody know the mistake ?

Comment: There is still a question on first page of asking exactly the same thing!

Comment: @SilentGhost: note that not only the question is duplicate, but some of the answers are also almost exact copy-paste duplicates. I fail to see any sense in these 'activities'.

Answer (score 6):

you need `itertools.izip_longest()` here or `itertools.zip_longest()` if you're on python 3.x:

```
In [1]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [2]: strs1="abc"

In [3]: strs2="defgh"

In [4]: "".join("".join(x) for x in izip_longest(strs1,strs2,fillvalue=""))
Out[4]: 'adbecfgh'
```

Comment: As a note, this is renamed to ``zip_longest()`` in 3.x, but +1 for a simple answer.

Comment: Yeap its work :)  But is there any other simple way to do this ? I mean using simple variables like counter and length and all..?

Comment: @NishaKothari see my other solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208159/846892), but I guess zip_longest() is simple enough and accept this the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the `roundrobin()` recipe from [the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Note [the slight differences for 2.x users](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

For example:

```
>>> "".join(roundrobin("abc", "defgh"))
adbecfgh
```

Comment: That doesn't put the strings in the desired order

Comment: @JakobBowyer Indeed, misread the question, updated.

Comment: Remember to import islice from itertools

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'abc'
y = 'defgh'
z = [x, y]

from itertools import izip_longest
print ''.join(''.join(i) for i in izip_longest(*z, fillvalue=''))
```